# In LLVM, how do you get the all the instructions that is not inside the starting part of loop?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I have a code

```
#pragma omp for
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
   A[i] = A[i] * B[i];
}
```

After I compile it to LLVM IR, I need to get the instructions only that is not inside the "for" part (incremental operation), because I only want to get the instructions that is related to `A[i] = A[i] * B[i]`. How do I do that?

Comment: what if it was `for (i = 0; i < length; A[i-1] = A[i-1] * B[i-1]) {i++;}`? Would you still not want the increment part? The compiler sees them the same, probably.

Comment: yes If that is the case, then I want only the `i++`

Comment: I would guess that difference does not exist in the IR. Because those are two programs that do exactly the same thing I would expect the exact same IR.

Comment: There's an analysis pass called [LoopInfo](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LoopInfo.html) that provides around two thirds of what you want. The rest is easy to implement using LoopInfo and a little more, at least until you consider loops like `while(true) { if(a) break; b(); c(d); if(e > d) break; f(g(d) + c); }` where the division between the two parts of the loop body is less simple. Or something as simple as `while(a(b)) c(b);` where `a()` has side effects.